# Ordering Complex Numbers

Tags: complex-numbers, order-theory

I am currently writing a piece of code that will order complex numbers, however I am not sure how to order them. For example, if I am given the numbers: 6, 3+4i, -4, 1+i and 0, how would these be ordered?

Is it sufficient just to take the magnitude of each number and order them that way?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: consider [lexicographical order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order)

Comment: By magnitude you mean absolute value? Then we will have to agree that $-5>2$. Also, what will be bigger-$1$ or $i$?

Comment: taking the magnitude loses the distinction between $1$ and $i$ for example

Comment: There is not a good order on the complex numbers as in the reals. You could use lexicographic ordering on the real and imaginary part, or on modulus and argument, if you prefer.

Comment: Cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1032257/ordering-of-the-complex-numbers)

Comment: complex numbers can be ordered, but not compatibly with field operations (addition, multiplication)

Comment: What is the purpose of ordering them?

Answer (score 0):

This depends entirely on your implementation. 
Note that when using magnitude for ordering that different elements can have the same magnitude. E.g. $i$ and $1$.

Answer (score 0):

It's up to you, since there is no standard ordering in the complex field. You could order them by magnitude, or you could - for example - use the lexicographic order: w > z if the real part of w is bigger than the real part of z. If the two real parts are equal, w > z if the imaginary part of w is bigger than the imaginary part of z.